# Extent Intersection when WrapAround180 enabled

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, extents

Allowing WrapAround180 allows map extents to go beyond the true Web Mercator extent. Once this happens I am not able to use map.extent.intersects(point). My work around was to

1. Normalize extents in lat/long
2. Convert point to lat/long
3. Split extents to two parts if crossing date line.
4. Test intersection with extent(s)

Is there an easier way?

Here's my code:

var extent = map.extent;
         var pointToTest = someGraphic;

```
     var normMin = wmUtils.xyToLngLat(extent.xmin, extent.ymin); 

     var normMax = wmUtils.xyToLngLat(extent.xmax, extent.ymax);


     //test if minx is greated than maxx
     if (normMin[0]> normMax[0]) {

      var pointMin1 = new Point([normMin[0],normMin[1]],new SR({ wkid:4326 }));
      var pointMin2 = new Point([180,normMax[1]],new SR({ wkid:4326 }));
      var wmMin1 = wmUtils.geographicToWebMercator(pointMin1);
      var wmMin2 = wmUtils.geographicToWebMercator(pointMin2);

      var pointMax1 = new Point([-180,normMin[1]],new SR({ wkid:4326 }));
      var pointMax2 = new Point([normMax[0],normMax[1]],new SR({ wkid:4326 }));
      var wmMax1= wmUtils.geographicToWebMercator(pointMax1);
      var wmMax2= wmUtils.geographicToWebMercator(pointMax2);


      var normExtent1 = new Extent(wmMin1.x,wmMin1.y,wmMin2.x,wmMin2.y, new SR({ wkid:102100 }));
      var normExtent2 = new Extent(wmMax1.x,wmMax1.y,wmMax2.x,wmMax2.y, new SR({ wkid:102100 }));

    } else {

     var pointMin = new Point(normMin,new SR({ wkid:4326 }));
     var wmMin = wmUtils.geographicToWebMercator(pointMin);
     var pointMax = new Point(normMax,new SR({ wkid:4326 }));
     var wmMax = wmUtils.geographicToWebMercator(pointMax);
     var normalizedExtent = new Extent(wmMin.x,wmMin.y,wmMax.x,wmMax.y, new SR({ wkid:102100 }));

   }

   if (normMin[0]> normMax[0]) {
        if ((!normExtent1.intersects(pointToTest.geometry) && !normExtent2.intersects(pointToTest.geometry))) return;
      } else {            
        if (!normalizedExtent.intersects(pointToTest.geometry)) return;
   }
```

Comment: Can you post the code you're using to do this? I'm curious to see exactly what you're doing.

Comment: Updated with code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an internal method on Extents, _normalize, that will do this for you. For instance, when you've wrapped the map around a couple of times, and you have a point:

```
var p = new Point(-100, 40);
```

This will return false:

```
map.extent.intersects(p); // false
```

While this will work:

```
map.extent._normalize().intersects(p); // true
```

Comment: That's great. Will that work when the dateline is visible?